# Группировка и нормализация данных

Tags: r

Дана таблица csv, которая записана в объект `rus` и в которой n столбцов. В первом столбце указаны несколько видов продукции, каждый тип продукции имеет по 10-20 строк. В остальных столбцах нужно изменить значения по функции `(х-а)/(b-a)` для каждой продукции, где х - конкретное значение столбца, b и а -  максимальные и минимальные значения для каждого продукта отдельно.

Пример:

```
Продукция Год  Продано Куплено Ожидается
Томаты    1992 20      30      40
Томаты    1993 50      10      40
Томаты    1994 30      40      60
Огурцы    1992 20      30      40
Огурцы    1993 50      80      10
Огурцы    1994 120     150     40
```

Нужно нормализовать в каждом столбике данные для каждого продукта, чтоб выглядело примерно так  ( и нормальны ли отрицательные значения или надо на -1 домножить?

```
Томаты 1992 0   0.6 0
Томаты 1993 0.5 0   0
Томаты 1994 0.3 1   1
Огурцы 1992 0   0   1
Огурцы 1993 0.3 0.4 0
Огурцы 1994 1   1   1
```

(для томатов отдельно нормализация была и для огурцов)

1) Как написать цикл, чтоб он мог нормализовать значения в конкретном столбце в диапазоне одного продукта для всех продуктов?

2) Возможно ли прогнать так через все столбцы?

Comment: а почему, например, у томатов за 1993 год продано "0.5"? это не совпадает с приведённой вами формулой. по ней должно быть "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2) Возможно ли прогнать так через все столбцы?

предположим, что ваши данные находятся в кадре данных (`data.frame`) под именем `f`:

```
f
#   Продукция  Год Продано Куплено Ожидается
# 1    Томаты 1992      20      30        40
# 2    Томаты 1993      50      10        40
# 3    Томаты 1994      30      40        60
# 4    Огурцы 1992      20      30        40
# 5    Огурцы 1993      50      80        10
# 6    Огурцы 1994     120     150        40
```

удобнее всего будет не городить всякие там циклы, а воспользоваться возможностями, предоставляемыми пакетом [*dplyr*](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
```

для начала стоит отдельно описать вашу функцию нормализации (возможно, её реализация и имеется где-то в недрах пакетной системы *r*, но написать самому будет быстрее):

```
myfun <- function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

а теперь всё готово для «магии» *dplyr*:

```
f %>% group_by(Продукция) %>% mutate_at(myfun, .vars=c("Продано","Куплено","Ожидается"))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups:   Продукция [2]
#   Продукция   Год Продано Куплено Ожидается
#   <fct>     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 Томаты     1992   0       0.667         0
# 2 Томаты     1993   1       0             0
# 3 Томаты     1994   0.333   1             1
# 4 Огурцы     1992   0       0             1
# 5 Огурцы     1993   0.3     0.417         0
# 6 Огурцы     1994   1       1             1
```

здесь:

- `%>%` — это аналог posix-овской вертикальной черты "`|`" — «трубы» («конвейера», «pipe»), позволяющей передавать данные из выхода одной сущности на вход другой;
- `group_by()` — группировать данные по указанному столбцу;
- `mutate_at()` — применить указанную функцию к указанным столбцам.

---

p.s. функции пакета *dplyr* нынче автоматом используют тип данных *tibble*. если надо результат преобразовать в тип «кадр данных», добавьте к «конвейеру» ещё вызов функции `as.data.frame`:

```
... %>% as.data.frame
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попытался применить в своей программе: rfa %>% group_by(rfa$country) %>% mutate_at(myfun, .vars=c(rfa$crop_land, rfa$grazing_land, rfa$forest_land, rfa$fishing_ground, rfa$built_up_land, rfa$carbon, rfa$total, rfa$percapita, rfa$population)), но выдает ошибку 
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a double vector  Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: вы подствляете значения столбцов, а ожидаются строки с именами (или номера) столбцов: `.vars=c("crop_land", "grazing_land", ...)` или `.vars=c(3, 4, ...)`

Comment: и функции `group_by()` надо передавать не значение, а имя столбца (здесь можно без кавычек): `group_by(country)`. в общем, вписывайте всё ровно так, как в примере.

Comment: Добрый день. Ещё раз спасибо за ваше решение. Позже попробовал сам написать функцию, без использования dplyr. На первых строках она даёт корректный результат, как и ваша функция, однако ближе к концу она и вовсе не работает с некоторыми данными. Можете пожалуйста посмотреть мою функцию? https://pastebin.com/s44N8jMv

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы